# webuse drugtr code does not work in Stata

Tags: stata

This code does not work in Stata:

```
webuse drugtr
no; data in memory would be lost
```

Do I need to install a package? What can I do to run this code?

Answer (score 2):

As the error mentions, you should have data already loaded into Stata, and it's warning you that `data in memory would be lost`.

Adding the option  `, clear` should solve it because it will tell Stata that it is okay to lose the previously loaded data.

For example, this will **not** work:

```
clear all
// create a one variable data set called x1 
// that contains 100 observations with the number one.
set obs 100
gen x1 = 1
*your line
webuse drugtr 
*no; data in memory would be lost
*r(4);
```

This **will** work

```
clear all
// create a one-variable data set called x1 
// that contains 100 observations with the number one.
set obs 100
gen x1 = 1
*your line
webuse drugtr , clear
*(Patient Survival in Drug Trial)
```

Therefore you do not have to install any packages to load the data.

Comment: I use        ,clear                   and my problem is resolved. Thank you

Comment: @Cgdmm It is customary on StackOverflow to accept the answer when it solves your problem.